# Elastic Search Query Performance

Tags: elasticsearch, query-performance

How can I measure the performance of a query in Elastic Search?
Any tool that can help me do this?

I need to find if the query is efficient or not.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://goo.gl/2ndqE2)